# What is Bizible JS and what function does it serve on the blog?

Tags: discussion, blog

I'm seeing a [tracking pixel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_beacon) called "bizible" on the blog. What is it doing?

Comment: Collecting even more data you don't need?

Comment: Ugh.  How distasteful is this?

Answer (score 7):

We've been using two tracking pixels that aren't needed anymore: Demandbase and HubSpot. We will be removing those. Going forward, we're going to use a single one called Bizible.

The goal is to help us better understand how our blog content contributes to our business.

**How it works (summary):**
Bizible JavaScript tracks web page visits (including anonymous visits), general page navigation, content downloads, and form fill completions on Stack Overflow’s Blog and marketing campaign pages. Bizible JavaScript does not function on the Stackoverflow.com domain. The captured data is pushed over to our internal CRM and each interaction is used to help Stack Overflow’s Marketing Team understand what type of content is most valuable for our business customers.

**How it works (detailed):**
Once the lead/contact visits the site and provides their email address on a form, the Bizible tracking JavaScript then connects information from the lead/contact records pushed over from our CRM via a cookie for each individual user. Bizible then reconciles the previously anonymous data and links it to the matching email address/criteria in the CRM.

The Bizible cookies loaded onto the page via the custom script each do the following:

- Universal user id to identify the same user across multiple clients’ domains
- User id on the current domain
- Session id of the user
- A single cookie that stores multiple information, such as whether or not the user has submitted a form, performed a crossdomain migration, sent a viewthrough pixel, opted out from tracking, etc
- Sequence number that Bizible includes for all requests, for internal diagnostic purpose
- Temporarily stores form submission data that happens before Bizible.js receives a configuration JS to determine whether or not tracking form on HTTPS is enabled
- Temporarily stores analytics data that has not been successfully sent to Bizible server yet

Comment: @Tim Did you mean to remove the summary in your first edit? I suspect you were just trying to format the bulleted list and accidentally removed it, but I can't be sure, so I didn't want to just reinstate it myself.

Comment: I hate these things.

Comment: Unfortunately, your tracking pixel can't tell you how many people don't visit your blog at all, in order to avoid tracking pixels.

Comment: "Universal user id to identify the same user across multiple clients’ domains" *adds to script blocker*