# Stack Overflow still wants to know my location

Tags: support, bug, privacy

I just entered the website via Google and the following popup occurred:

[image: Stack Overflow wants to know your location.]

Given [Nick Craver's answer from 1.5 years ago](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/378655/3305454) was:

> We don't. This is a rogue extension or ad most likely and we'll get to the bottom of it.

I suppose this is another rogue extension? Or is this something the marketing team intended?

(Latest MacOS, latest Chrome version, using uBlock Origin while visiting the site, and [this is the exact URL I was visiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22766111/ffmpeg-not-working-with-filenames-that-have-whitespace))

Comment: Just another bad ad most likely

Comment: They’re looking into it. See MSE dupe: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/349467/323179

Comment: @Laurel I feel a bit silly for not allowing it, while also tracking exactly which browser elements were using it now. Oh well.

Comment: You might be able to withdraw the block without explicitly allowing it - at least you can in firefox. It's like resetting the "do not ask" switch without answering the question. That being said, keep in mind that SE have really come to embrace fingerprinting (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/399248/6296561 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332229/332043 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/332974/332043), and location is a great way to contribute to fingerprinting data. Could be a bad ad, but the marketing team doing it intentionally is sadly a real risk

Comment: Also, from the privacy policy: "When you use the Stack Overflow Network, and certain of our Products and Services, we collect location information about you including your IP address, your location, browser information, and how you came to the Stack Overflow Network" , as well as "You may revoke our permission to collect some of this data, including your location and browser information through your Account Settings" - could be Jobs has started polling locations actively. Surprised uBlock didn't nuke that though - I can't repro it with my overkill layer of defense in Firefox.

Comment: I'm on Latest MacOS, latest Chrome and never get this and have "ask" for location as default.